# why would'nt the player move? when i press the button no movement takes place

Tags: godot, gdscript

I just started learning Godot and don't understand why the player would not move? here is the script attached to the player

```
extends CharacterBody2D
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
func _physics_process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        velocity.x = 4
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        velocity.x = -4
    else:
        velocity = 0
        
move_and_collide(velocity)
```

Comment: First thing I see is that the indentation is wrong. The call `move_and_collide(velocity)` would be outside of `_physics_process`. So are you getting errors when you execute the code?

Comment: You also setting `velocity` to `0`. I think this is all typos.

Comment: yes i got an error it says "Line 11:Unexpected "Identifier" in class body."

Comment: I think you have to call `set_process_input(true)` in `_ready()` as you don't have an `_input()` method, which normally enables input processing.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple small errors in your code that prevent your Character from moving.

**First**: the `move_and_collide()` function is outside of the `_physics_process()` function. To fix this, you simply have to indent `move_and_collide()`. It will look something like this:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        velocity.x = 4
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        velocity.x = -4
    else:
        velocity = 0
    move_and_collide(velocity)
```

Now `move_and_collide()` will be inside of the `_physics_process()` loop.

**Second**: for a CharacterBody2D, the `variable` velocity already exists (This is new to Godot 4 I believe).
In line 2:

```
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
```

You are trying to redefine the variable. To fix this all you have to do is remove the `var` and make it `velocity = Vector2.ZERO`. You could also simply remove this line completely, which I would suggest.

**Third**: This is a small mistake, but on line 9, you are trying to assign the value `0` to the variable `velocity`, which is a `Vector2` and not an `Integer`. To fix this simply change `velocity` to `velocity.x`

The final code would look like this:

```
extends CharacterBody2D
func _physics_process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        velocity.x = 4
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        velocity.x = -4
    else:
        velocity.x = 0
    move_and_collide(velocity)
```